# Colorize PNG using PHP GD

Tags: php, gd, php-gd, colorize

I want to colorize some PNGs using PHP GD. For testing purpose i hardcoded the color red (255,0,0) which later will be replace by a dynamic variable.

For example i have these two images:

Image 1: [image: 6Bt.png]

Image 2: [image: 6Bd.png]

Using my code, only image 2 works as it should.
[image: 6BC.png]

The dog image however has some sort of gray box, don't know where the heck this comes from.
[image: 6BA.png]

Here is the code I'm using:

```php
<?php

$im = imagecreatefrompng('dog.png');

imagealphablending($im, false);
imagesavealpha($im, true);

$w = imagesx($im);
$h = imagesy($im);

for ($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $h; $y++) {
        $color = imagecolorsforindex($im, imagecolorat($im, $x, $y));

        $r = ($color['red'] * 255) / 255;
        $g = ($color['green'] * 0) / 255;
        $b = ($color['blue'] * 0) / 255;

        imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($im, $r, $g, $b, $color['alpha']));
    }
}

imagepng($im, 'result.png');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Why does it work with image 2 but not image 1? I only can think of some sort of alpha mask going on with image 1.

Hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 1):

This could be more easily done using `imagefilter()`:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng('dog.png');
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 255, 0, 0);
imagepng($im, 'result.png');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Yeah but now the color is wrong. Its to light already tried this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not mentioned in the documentation for `imagecolorallocate()` or its alpha equivalent, but someone has pointed out [in the comments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php#94785) that you can only allocate 255 colours in the image before running out. Check that the allocation hasn't failed before using the new colour. If it has, use `imagecolorclosestalpha()` to get the next best thing.

```
<?php
$replace = [255, 0, 0];
array_walk($replace, function(&$v, $k) {$v /= 255;});

$im = imagecreatefrompng('dog.png');

for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); $y++) {
        $color = imagecolorsforindex($im, imagecolorat($im, $x, $y));

        $r = $color["red"] * $replace[0];
        $g = $color["green"] * $replace[1];
        $b = $color["blue"] * $replace[2];
        $a = $color["alpha"];
        $newcolour = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, $r, $g, $b, $a);
        if ($newcolour === false) {
            $newcolour = imagecolorclosestalpha($im, $r, $g, $b, $a);
        }
        imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $newcolour);
    }
}

imagepng($im, 'result.png');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Output: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'v got it working using my code. All i had to do is add `imagepalettetotruecolor($im);`